# Обращение к элементам массива в обработчике события

Tags: c#, wpf

На форме имеется кнопка, нажать которую можно будет только определенное количество раз. Чтобы это реализовать, я создал статичное поле, а в обработчике события нажатия по кнопке проверял, не превышено ли значение. После первого же нажатия вылезает ошибка о нахождении за пределами массива. Пробовал изменить значение по конкретному индексу - не помогло, все равно оказывался за пределами массива.

```
    private int[] R;
    private static int k = 0;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            
        button2.IsEnabled = false;
        R = new int[N];
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (k < 5)
        {
            Int32.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out R[k]);
            k++;
        }
        else
            button2.IsEnabled = false;
    }
```

Comment: А что такое `R`?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ подправил

Comment: Ну вот теперь понятно в чем ошибка хотя бы. А зачем вам этот R? Ошибка в том, что массивы всегда фиксированного размера, вы его создаете изначально с N (то есть 0), то есть ваш массив размера 0 элементов. Сделайте повторную инициализацию массива и копируйте туда старые элементы. Но только опять же, зачем `R`? В чем его смысл?

Comment: Я кажется  понял в чем смысл, вы пытаетесь собрать 5 значений в массиве от пользователя, так? Тогда идите в другую сторону, от 5 до 0, отнимая `k`. Не забывайте, что массив всегда фиксированной длины, той, которая задана при инициализации. Либо вовсе используйте `List<int>`, он не имеет фиксированной длины.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ действительно, во время инициализации N = 0. И только потом его значение меняется, но массив уже создан из нуля элементов оказывается. R нужен для того, чтобы хранить значения из textBox2. Спасибо!

Comment: Напишите ваш вариант решения в ответ пожалуйста. Закроем и забудем )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для исправления нужно было отодвинуть инициализацию массива на тот момент, когда N уже задан. Изначально получалось так, что я сначала инициализировал массив, а потом изменял значение N на неравное 0. В итоге создавался массив из 0 элементов.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public int N { get; set; }
        private int[] R;
        private static int k = 0;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();            
            button2.IsEnabled = false;
        }

        public int GetMonthsCount()
        {
            if (Int32.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out int count))
                return count;
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Неправильный формат данных");
                return -1;
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            N = GetMonthsCount();
            button1.IsEnabled = false;
            button2.IsEnabled = true;
            R = new int[N];
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (k < (N - 1))
            {
                Int32.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out R[k]);
                k++;
            }
            else
                button2.IsEnabled = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: В следующий раз используйте более понятные имена, а не `N` `R` `k`. Сокращение кода не делает его лучше или быстрее, а разбираться в нем становится гораздо трудней.